# How to do SSO for grafana? I am trying to embed grafana inside servicenow using iframe

Tags: iframe, ldap, grafana, servicenow

How to do SSO for grafana? I am trying to embed grafana inside servicenow tool using iframe. I am aware that this can be achieved using anonymous authentication feature in grafana. But this needs to be accomplished in a secured way. Servicenow tool uses ldap or AD users for authentication. Please help if someone knows more about it.